# Prove Hölder continuity of power function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, education, holder-spaces

How can I prove that $f(x)=x^s$ for $0< s ≤1$ is Hölder-continuous with constant s?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving that $f(x) = x^s$ is holder continuous with holder exponent s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070706/proving-that-fx-xs-is-holder-continuous-with-holder-exponent-s)

Comment: The proofs in that link do not seem really convincing. I want to show that the constant of Hölder continuity is s.

Comment: I started by assuming that x>y and then I tried to use difference of powers formula but it doesn't work here. I can neither use limits of two variable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The result is true for $s=1,$ so assume $0<s<1.$ Suppose $0\le x.$ We'll be done if we show $y^s-x^s \le (y-x)^s$ for $y\ge x.$ Define $f(y) = y^s-x^s - (y-x)^s.$ Show $f'(y) < 0$ on $(x,\infty)$ to see $f$ decreases on $[x,\infty).$